# Set value of column to 0 for only one of the duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table, and I want to set the value of deleted column to zero for only one of the records that have duplicate names.

```
id     name      deleted
------------------------
1      a         1
2      a         1
3      a         1
4      b         1
5      c         1
6      d         1
```

so the output will be:

```
id     name      deleted
------------------------
1      a         0
2      a         1
3      a         1
4      b         0
5      c         0
6      d         0
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: update table with an inner select, but no luck

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later you can do this fairly easily with a CTE and Row_Number(). This is probably why @TimSchmelter was asking which RDBMS you're using ... as I was writing this he provided that exact answer. :)

Comment: Yeppers, clean, gotta love it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dbms is SQL-Server( >= 2005) you can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ID, Name, Deleted,
     RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ID)
   FROM dbo.T
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Deleted = 0
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c0b2/7/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Tbl SET deleted = 0 WHERE id IN
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM Tbl GROUP BY name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE A
SET A.deleted = 0
FROM Tbl A
   LEFT JOIN Tbl B
     ON A.Name = B.Name
        AND A.Id > B.Id
WHERE B.Id IS NULL
```